# Multiple CSS conditional classes using React

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to incorporate 3 *more* conditional classes into this...

```
<li className={`list-group-item ${todo.completed ? " strike-through" : ""}`}
```

I now want `${todo.priority}` to be included/alongside with this, which will assign classes:

"alert alert-info",
"alert alert-warning",
and
"alert alert-danger"
based on corresponding values in a drop down: 1, 2, 3.

Can someone help me with this, thank you in advance!

Comment: Will `todo.priority` be alongside `todo.completed`, or only one of the two?

Comment: Alongside, thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Others have already provided some more "flexible" solutions, so I'll just add the quick and dirty one:

```
<li className={`list-group-item ${todo.completed ? " strike-through" : ""} ${todo.priority === 1 ? "alert alert-info" : (todo.priority === 2 ? "alert alert-warning" : "alert alert-danger")}`} />
```

For readability's sake:

```
const completed = todo.completed ? " strike-through" : "";
const priority = todo.priority === 1 ? "alert alert-info" : (todo.priority === 2 ? "alert alert-warning" : "alert alert-danger");
...
<li className={`list-group-item ${completed} ${priority}`} />
```

Answer (score 10):

I recommend the [`classnames`](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) package. It's a widely-used package and serves a straightforward purpose. Any key whose value is truthy will make it into the final class name:

```
import cx from 'classnames';

<li className={cx('list-group-item', {
   'alert alert-danger': value === 3,
   'alert alert-info': value === 1,
   'alert alert-warning': value === 2,
   'strike-through': todo.completed,
})} />
```

Answer (score 6):

You could keep on adding classes in the same vein, or you could use a library like [`classnames`](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) to make it a bit easier to compose classes.

**Example**

```
import React from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';

class App extends React.Component {
  // ...

  render() {
    // ...

    const className = classNames({
      'list-group-item': true,
      'strike-through': todo.completed,
      'alert alert-info': todo.priority === 1,
      'alert alert-warning': todo.priority === 2,
      'alert alert-danger': todo.priority === 3,
    });
    return <li className={className}> ... </li>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
import clsx from "clsx";

className={
  clsx(classes.firstClass,  
  { [classes.coach]: user.id === "F6E2080B-E61F-416D-8841-3E0249DF2715" })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const className = {
      'list-group-item': true,
      'strike-through': todo.completed,
      'alert alert-info': todo.priority === 1,
      'alert alert-warning': todo.priority === 2,
      'alert alert-danger': todo.priority === 3,
    }
  let classNameString = "";
  Object.entries(className).forEach((el) => {
    if (el[1]) {
      const str = el[0] + " ";
      classNameString += str;
    }
  });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).