# How should I write my classname before the expression?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

styles.nav__item seems not to work before the expression. How could I write this correctly to proceed styling?

```
import Link from "next/link";
import React from "react";
import styles from '../styles/Navbar.module.css'

const NavItem = ({ text, href, active }) => {
  return (
    <Link href={href}>
      <li
        className={`nav__item ${
          active ? styles.active : ""
        }`}
      >
        {text}
      </li>
    </Link>
  );
};

export default NavItem;
```

Comment: It's not clear what the issue is - you're not using `styles.nav__item` anywhere in that component.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
className={`nav__item ${active ? styles.axtive : ""}`}
```

Comment: If this doesn’t work, then the `styles.active` is not imported/implemented correctly.

Comment: Also take a look to this answer :   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53092209/multiple-css-conditional-classes-using-react